# No se puede modificar información de la cabecera - Las cabeceras han sido enviadas por

Tags: php, wordpress

actualmente tengo un problema al desarrollar una página en wordpress, y esto me tiene trabado a seguir con el resto de la página. En el error log del hosting, me muestra lo siguiente:

> **PHP Warning:**  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/media-template.php:165) in /home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 824, referer: http://telered.ec/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations
>
> **PHP Warning:**  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/media-template.php:165) in /home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 823, referer: http://telered.ec/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations

Entonces, revisé la página php "media-template.php" en la línea que me menciona(165) y dice lo siguiente:

```
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
```

Esto es parte de un script que lo pongo abajo:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-media-modal">
    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
        <button type="button" class="button-link media-modal-close"><span class="media-modal-icon"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Close media panel' ); ?></span></span></button>
        <div class="media-modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-modal-backdrop"></div>
</script>
```

Alguna idea del problema? Revisando ese código, es posible que esté bien realizado el tag div class y dentro un llamado php?

Comment: Hola Jorge bienvenido a SO en español, considera traducir tu pregunta a español, para obtener una respuesta, el sitio solo acepta preguntas en español, si quieres hacerla hacerla en ingles, puedes hacerlo en SO Inglés, https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JuanPinzón Hola, ya está traducido, no me fijé que estaba en el sitio en español.

Comment: Que tienes en la linea 823 y 824 como menciona el warning? `/home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 824`

Comment: Este es el 823
`setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );`
Y este es el 824
`setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );`

Comment: El problema está en ese archivo, revisa si no existen espacios en blanco antes de `<?php`, o despues de `?>`, tambien puedes revisar algunas soluciones en esta pregunta de SO inglés. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Actualmente he revisado los dos archivos, y realmente lo único que me genera duda es esta línea `<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">` @JuanPinzón

Comment: El `echo $class;` esta bien no hay problema, la función setcookie es la que modifica los headers, esa función si esta al inicio del script?

Comment: @Jorge deberías incluir a `wp-includes/option.php` **antes** de imprimir cualquier etiqueta del HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las cookies son enviadas como [encabezados HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Cabeceras). Por lo tanto, tienen que enviarse **antes de imprimir cualquier caracter** del cuerpo del HTML.

En tu caso, dentro del archivo `/home/teleredi/public_html/wp-includes/option.php`, se están seteando cookies **luego** de imprimir parte del cuerpo del HTML:

```
setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
```

Por lo tanto, deberías incluir a `wp-includes/option.php` **antes** de imprimir cualquier etiqueta del HTML (al principio del PHP). Y también hay que estar atento a que no haya espacios o saltos de línea antes de abrir la etiqueta `<?php`.

Este error, sin embargo, lo está generando el template `wp-includes/media-template.php`, por lo que deberías editarlo o contactar al autor del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema a ese conflicto es que existe un espacio en blanco antes de la etiqueta `<?php` la solución a ello es dejarlo sin espacio.